# Compile Linux kernel module for 32bit cpu

Tags: c, linux, kernel, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

I am learning how to make a Linux kernel module and i want to compile it for a 32bit CPU. How can I do that?

My current command to compile the kernel (which defaults to 64bit) is:

```
obj-m += test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

In gcc, I would use the `-m32` flag but in this case, I don't know how the Kernel compilation works, so I don't know what to change.

Comment: I think the best way is that you install a 32 bit SO into a VM and you manage your project inside it. This is because you need some references to the kernel which have to use the module you want generate!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross compile the module. Please take a look at this page http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/KernelCrossCompilation .